# Zookeeper startup issues/confusion

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, linux-mint

Apart from [the issue I am already having](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJti9bBHBCU), I installed Zookeeper BEFORE  I installed HBase (it's still not installed), after [I saw a video on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJti9bBHBCU). While installing it, I faced numerous issue, which I've now overcome, but I am left with one challenging one; probably the only one I will have to. So, the installation part has gone through well. I start zookeeper with the following command: `sudo /home/hduser/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start` and (I am ok with it because) this is the result:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hduser/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

YES! IT'S STARTED (after almost 50 mintutes of digging on the internet). But nevertheless, when I `jps`, this is what I get:

```
8499 SecondaryNameNode
8162 NameNode
8983 NodeManager
9370 Jps
8313 DataNode
8672 ResourceManager
```

Exactly!! No `QuorumPeerMain`! BUT wait.. When I `sudo jps`, I get this:

```
8499 -- process information unavailable
9243 QuorumPeerMain
8162 -- process information unavailable
8983 -- process information unavailable
9429 Jps
8313 -- process information unavailable
8672 -- process information unavailable
```

You see there? There's the `QuorumPeerMain` (minus the fact that it say `process information unavailable` against the perfectly relatable processes), riding the process `9243`.

Can you tell me why that's happeneing?

Also, because of this discrepancy (or inconvenience), do you think HBase installation will be an issue?

I don't think it should matter, but this is a Mint machine (`Sarah`).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuorumPeerMain service is visible with sudo jps command because you are running the Zookeeper with `sudo /home/hduser/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh`. You should run the Zookeeper without sudo in command then it will be visible in jps command result.

As you have started the Zookeeper with sudo the Zookeeper directory is having the files with root permissions you have to update the owner of these directories to run it with normal command.

Once you make above changes the hbase installation will not create any problem.

Comment: Ok. this is what I get when i do not use sudo:

`ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/hduser/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... /home/hduser/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh: line 149: /home/hduser/zookeeperData/zookeeper_server.pid: Permission denied
FAILED TO WRITE PID`. Anything help!?

Comment: That's why i mentioned you have to change the ownership of the zookeeperData folder using below command:
`sudo chown -R hduser:hduser /home/hduser/zookeeperData`

Comment: Oh that was it. Thanks lot :)

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer. Thanks.